# How to call a method of View in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to call a method of the View in the ViewNodel because in the View I can access different things that in the ViewModel not and I need to call that method. Is this possible to do?

Method in View:

```
  private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Book book = null;
        if (sender is StackLayout)
        {
            book = ((StackLayout)sender).BindingContext as Book;

            if (null == viewModel.BookSelected || !book.BookId.Equals(viewModel.BookSelected.BookId))
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you shouldn't ... seems like XY problem. What exactly you wana do with View from ViewModel?

Comment: that defeats the purpose of MVVM.  Your VM can raise events that your View responds to

Comment: @LololYot Please check answer, I think it will work for you. :)

Comment: @Selvin In my view I have a sender to open an expander, I edit my post with the method I have in the View

Comment: Then expander is badly written... For WPF it should have Expanded bool dependency property which could be easily binded from ViewModel, instead calling a method

Comment: Check my edited post, I added my method

Comment: @LololYut When will this method be called? Trying to use binding in viewmodel?

Comment: Yes, with whatever. Mainly I would like to do it without breaking the MVVM but if not possible there is no other alternative

Comment: @LololYut have you checked the updated answer? Please check and let me know .:)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is quite possible to access everything from view to viewmodel. If you are unable to do that in certain situation then, you can use `event` in your VM and raise that event when you need and you can bind a method that you want to call. Please check my sample code.

```
    public class View
    {
        ViewModel myVM = null;
        public View()
        {
            myVM=new ViewModel();
            myVM.CallMyMethodEvent += myViewMethod;
        }
        void myViewMethod(bool param)
        {
            //do you thing
        }
    }
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public Action<bool> CallMyMethodEvent;

        private void RaiseEventToCallMethodInView()
        {
            if (CallMyMethodEvent != null)
            {
                CallMyMethodEvent.Invoke(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

**New Update** Code as you want to call `MyMethod()` with 2 parameters. So, the code will look like =>

```
public class View
    {
        ViewModel myVM = null;
        public View()
        {
            myVM.CallMyMethodWithEventArgEvent += MyMethod;
        }
        private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(sender is StackLayout)
            {
                var yourStackLayoutobject = (StackLayout)sender;
            }
        }
    }
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public Action<object, EventArgs> CallMyMethodWithEventArgEvent;
        private void RaiseEventToCallMethodWithEventArgInView()
        {
            if (CallMyMethodWithEventArgEvent != null)
            {
                CallMyMethodWithEventArgEvent.Invoke(new StackLayout(),null);
            }
        }
    }
    public class StackLayout
    {
    }
```

**NOTE:** Please check the code and let me know. I have used a dummy class `StackLayout` you can use your proper class.

Comment: How can I call my method If I need to use sender? Can you check my method in my post?

Comment: ok, let me check and can you explain what exactly you want. Best Wishes :)

Comment: I have the method that I have in my post which I use sender to handle elements of the view. My goal is to call that method in the viewmodel. I have used your code with the method you created called myViewMethod. Inside of your method, I called my method passing through sender parameters as null and eventargs as null. My method is called but when passing it as null my method does not work.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer (NEW Update Part). Please check now and let me know. :)

Comment: The method is called correctly but does not do its job in the view. When called it should change a visual aspect of the view but it does not. It must be because of the arguments